# What symbols/characters are not allowed in tags?

Tags: support, tags, special-characters

What symbols/characters are not allowed in tags?

Answer (score 10):

## What characters are allowed in tag names?

#### Always allowed

- lowercase Latin letters `a` to `z`
- digits `0` to `9`

#### Conditionally allowed

- plus `+`

  - *single* plus allowed at the end of tags: [gdi+](/questions/tagged/gdi%2b), [com+](/questions/tagged/com%2b), [im+](/questions/tagged/im%2b) ([query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/702881/tags-containing-single))
  - *double* plus `++` allowed anywhere ***except*** the start of a tag: [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [visual-c++-2010](/questions/tagged/visual-c%2b%2b-2010), [g++4.8](/questions/tagged/g%2b%2b4.8) ([query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/702724/tags-containing))
- hyphen `-`

  - allowed anywhere ***except*** the start or end of a tag: [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c), [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails), [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) ([query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/702764/tags-containing))
- number symbol (hash) `#`

  - allowed anywhere ***except*** the start of a tag: [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), [f#-interactive](/questions/tagged/f%23-interactive), [c#-to-f#](/questions/tagged/c%23-to-f%23) ([query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/702751/tags-containing))
- period `.`

  - allowed anywhere ***except*** the end of a tag: [.net](/questions/tagged/.net), [.htaccess](/questions/tagged/.htaccess), [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7)   ([query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/702779/tags-containing))
- accents `ã` and foreign language `ム`

  - Certain non-English sites allow special language specific characters
  - Examples: Stack Overflow in [Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), [Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), [Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/), [Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)

---

#### Related Questions

- [Tag names cannot end with hyphen (-)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298971/tag-names-cannot-end-with-hyphen)
- [Bug with tags with plus in name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77757/bug-with-tags-with-plus-in-name)
- [How can I create a tag that contains "+"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45353/how-can-i-create-a-tag-that-contains)

Answer (score 8):

On the sidebar it says that these are the Tag Characters:

Tag characters: [a-z 0-9 + # - .]

I'd assume anything not listed there is invalid.

Comment: Do you know what happens when you assume?

Comment: You get struck by lightning?

Comment: You split assume into an array by substring index 0,3 3,1 4,2

Comment: It's worth noting that `+` is only allowed at the ***end*** of a tag name.

Answer (score 3):

At least for chat room tags I was just able to create a tag [español](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tags/espa%C3%B1ol/info) for the [Spanish chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1792/sala-de-chat). I thought the system would automatically change it to `espanol` like it does for the question tags. So I went further and tried to create a `日本語` for the Japanese chat room, but it got converted to `???`.

So the answer may be:

- Some Latin-1 characters are no longer disallowed

or

- That subsets of characters not allowed in question tags is different to that not allowed in chat room tags

or

- There's a bug in chat room tags that allows you to use characters that are not supposed to be allowed