# What characters does Stack Overflow allow in tags?

Tags: support, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What symbols/characters are not allowed in tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22624/what-symbols-characters-are-not-allowed-in-tags)

I'm curious simply because I'm writing JS script that does tagging similar to SO, what characters are allowed in tags on SO?

Is it alphanumerics and some others like `#` and `_`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the side box that pops up when you are tagging a question:

> How to Tag A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question
>   with other, similar questions.
>
> ► favor existing popular tags; avoid creating new tags
>
> ► use common abbreviations
>
> ► don't include synonyms
>
> ► combine multiple words into single-words with dashes
>
> ► maximum of 5 tags, 25 chars per tag
>
> ► **tag characters: [a-z 0-9 + # - .]**
>
> ► delimit tags by space, semicolon, or comma

so out of your set, `_` is not permitted.

Comment: oh my. this's called selective dislexia.