# Tag names cannot end with hyphen (-)

Tags: bug, tags, special-characters

According to *[What symbols/characters are not allowed in tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22624/351462)*, the list of allowed tag characters are **[a-z 0-9 + # - .]**

Currently, it seems that tags ending in `-` don't work properly on Stack Exchange. So for example, if I had a question about [C--](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C--), I wouldn't be able to ask it on Stack Overflow

#### Allowed

- [`[tag:c++]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++): [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)
- [`[tag:gdi+]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gdi+): [gdi+](/questions/tagged/gdi%2b)
- [`[tag:notepad++]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/notepad++): [notepad++](/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b)

#### Not Allowed

- [`[tag:c--]`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C--): [c](/questions/tagged/c)
- [`[tag:v--]`](http://esolangs.org/wiki/V--): [v](/questions/tagged/v)
- [`[tag:brawl-]`](https://www.ssbwiki.com/brawl-): [brawl](/questions/tagged/brawl)

Is this naming limitation by design? If tag names can include `+`, is there a reason they can't end with `-`?

<sub>*Thanks to [Rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene) for their [SE Data Explorer query searching tags ending in `+` or `-`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/702675)</sub>

---

**Edit**: After experimenting with the SE Data Explorer, I've found that there are a few other hidden restrictions on tag names. (See [What symbols/characters are not allowed in tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298981/351462))

Comment: The minus sign is (only) in use as a hyphen between two words. Also, [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-minus-minus).

Comment: @Glorfindel I find it amusing that `+` can only be used at the end of a tag, while `-` can only be used in the middle.

Comment: Nitpick: that's not a minus sign, it's a hyphen. They are different.

Comment: The question is whether such a restriction is necessary; otherwise, in the face of a legitimate use case, there is no good reason to have it.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if allowing a - at the end of a tagname would break the tag engine, making Marc Gravell unhappy ...

Comment: @Cai Typography and semantics are not aligned here; nobody would read C-- as "C-hyphen-hyphen"...

Comment: @Alex sure, but we're not talking about semantics, we're talking about a technical limitation of allowed characters and a minus sign isn't allowed *anywhere* in a tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What symbols/characters are not allowed in tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22624/what-symbols-characters-are-not-allowed-in-tags)

Comment: @iBug: Not really. That's a more general one, but this is exploring a quirk of the restrictions that isn't stated clearly there.

Comment: @Glorfindel Actually, what the keyboard has is a [hyphen-minus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen-minus), which is used for a hyphen or a minus. In fact, the [numeric keypad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_keypad) has the same character already present in the keyboard.

Comment: Maybe it happens few times to use a tag like [tag:c--], but since C-- is the name of a programming language, I would at least expect Stack Overflow to allow users to use that tag.